# ERROR: java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, jdbc

Ayuda! Este es mi código necesito ingresar datos en Netbeans y que la información ingresada me aparezca en SQLyog

[image: este es el código 1]

[image: código 2]

[image: Esta es la Tabla que estoy utilizando]

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow. Por favor, no publiques código en imágenes. Edita tu pregunta y pega directamente el código problemático como parte de tu pregunta (como texto). Por otro lado, no confundas NetBeans, que es el IDE que utilizas para producir tu programa, con tu programa como tal. Tu no necesitas ingresar datos en NetBeans. Tu necesitas ingresar datos en tu programa, hecho en java, y que estos datos se almacenen en la base de datos.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask].

Comment: Hola, ¿Tu código debe de interactuar con [tag:SQLyog] o eso no es aprte del problema en sí?

Comment: Revisa las líneas 212 y 213 de tu archivo `Diseño.java`, al parecer hay un problema con las comillas simples.